# "message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'affiliateStats')"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, undefined

when i try to run this code it give me the error on my console.log

> "message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'affiliateStats')"

why does it happen?how can i make it work?
im new in ReactJs
Here's my code:

`

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import User from "../models/User.js";
import Transaction from "../models/Transaction.js";

export const getAdmins = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const admins = await User.find({ role: "admin" }).select("-password");
    res.status(200).json(admins);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

export const getUserPerformance = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;

    const userWithStats = await User.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "affiliatestats",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "affiliateStats",
        },
      },
      { $unwind: "$affiliateStats" },
    ]);

    const saleTransactions = await Promise.all(
      userWithStats[0].affiliateStats.affiliateSales.map((id) => {
        return Transaction.findById(id);
      })
    );
    const filteredSaleTransactions = saleTransactions.filter(
      (transaction) => transaction !== null
    );

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ user: userWithStats[0], sales: filteredSaleTransactions });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

`

Comment: This means that your userWithStats is an empty array.  Either no user exists with that id, or there is a problem with your mongo query.

Comment: I’m removing the reactjs and redux tags and adding the mongoose tag because that’s where your problem is.  That’s not my area of expertise.  Hopefully someone with more mongoose knowledge can spot the problem.

Comment: You have a typo in `as: "affiliateSstats"` - extra s.

Comment: @Aurast right, thank you so much. But it still give me the error

Answer (score 0):

There may be two causes:

1. problem with match statement, the returning data is empty
2. lookup is returning empty array and unwind does not have  `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: <boolean>` which yields to empty result

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial. I did some research and found that it cannot map on undefined values and I believe the one in question is affiliateSales. To fix it I initialized const { affiliateSales } = []; underneath const { id } = req.params;. Hope this helps

Comment: so where i must put affiliateSales?
`userWithStats[0].affiliateStats.affiliateSales.map( async (id)`